# Memory layout of C# array of struct

Tags: c#

In C, if I have the following struct `Data`:

```
struct __attribute__((__packed__)) Data
{
    double x;
    int y;
};
```

And then create an array named `val` of this struct:

```
Data val[3];
```

All values stored in `val` (i.e. `val[0].x`, `val[0].y`, `val[1].x`, `val[1].y`, `val[2].x` and `val[2].y` are contiguous in memory.

Now, when having the following struct in C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=0)]
struct Data
{
    public double x;
    public int y;
}
```

And then create an array named `val` of this struct:

```
Data val[3];
```

I would expect that all values stored in `val` are contiguous in memory, which they are not (based on the tests that I have conducted). In details, `val[0].x` and `val[0].y` are both contiguous, but they are not contiguous with `val[1]` (which, in turn, is not contiguous with `val[2]`).

My question is: in C#, how can I create a variable (that is an array) of a certain struct that all its elements and members are contiguous in memory?

Comment: Arrays are stored contigous by default. Except when a reference type is used. In that case only references are contigous.

Comment: Can you show us those tests? What you say contradicts the normal implementations of arrays (which is having them contiguous for value type-only arrays). Have you tried pinning a `fixed` pointer to `&val[0]`?

Comment: @user7698505 no, but `Pack=0` means "default padding", and what you are looking at is packing at the least possible. That'd be `Pack=1` in C# I believe

Comment: @user7698505: it solved the issue. Thank you very much for all the comments above!

Comment: I'm curious what the use case is behind this question. Setting `Pack=1` can cause issues (speed and/or stability). Are you doing the for managed/native interop reasons, or something else?

Comment: @Flydog57, typically because you ran out of the memory or you have to match some constraints which you have no control of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to try it, I made a very simple project: using `Pack=1` seems to pack perfectly fine to the smallest byte.

Reproducing code (on a console app):

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]
struct Data
{
    public double x;
    public int y;
}

class Program {
    static void Main()
    {
        Data[] val = new Data[3] {
            new Data { x = 0, y = 0 },
            new Data { x = 1, y = 1 },
            new Data { x = 2, y = 2 },
        };

        for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("data[" + i + "].x = " + BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(val[i].x)));
            Console.WriteLine("data[" + i + "].y = " + BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(val[i].y)));
        }       

        unsafe {
            fixed (Data *p = &val[0])
            {
                byte *c = (byte *)p;
                for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    for(var i = 0; i < Marshal.SizeOf<double>(); i++, c++)
                    {
                        if(i!=0) Console.Write("-");
                        Console.Write("{0:X2}", *c);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    for(var i = 0; i < Marshal.SizeOf<int>(); i++, c++)
                    {
                        if(i!=0) Console.Write("-");
                        Console.Write("{0:X2}", *c);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
data[0].x = 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
data[0].y = 00-00-00-00
data[1].x = 00-00-00-00-00-00-F0-3F
data[1].y = 01-00-00-00
data[2].x = 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-40
data[2].y = 02-00-00-00
00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
00-00-00-00
00-00-00-00-00-00-F0-3F
01-00-00-00
00-00-00-00-00-00-00-40
02-00-00-00
```

Which looks perfectly continuous to me, unless I'm missing something